# How to get limited results per page in django using pagination?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am following a udemy course where I am making a real estate website using Django. I have come so far and have been fighting with the errors but I am stuck with the pagination error that I am facing right now.

I see everything is working fine in the video but when I follow it exactly it does not work. **The issue is that when I set a limit on items per page, it does not seem to be working as I see all the results on the same page.**

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from .models import Listing

def index(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    paginator = Paginator(listings, 3)

    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    context = {
        'listings': listings
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/listings.html', context)
```

It's my Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='listings'),
    path('<int:listings_id>', views.listing, name='listing'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search')
```

As you can see, I have set maximum 3 listings per page but I am getting all of them on a single page which is not what I want. It would be great if anyone could help. Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning whole listings instead of Paginator page inside of context

```
context = {
    'listings': page_obj
}
```

More regarding pagination you can check also in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/#pagination)